# Need explanation on logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I'm messing around with Spring Data, and tryna see what happens at the time repository save new entity by using Logging. Easy solution: just 2 lines of properties into application.properties

`logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder = TRACE
 logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL = TRACE`

but I wonder 2 things:
1) Why Intellij doesn't autocomplete for me at `logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL = TRACE` (I'm using Intellij Ultimate - Student license (Version: 2019.3.3))
2) Why there isn't any documentation on org.hibernate.SQL, and maybe it is the reason why Intellij can't suggest it (I tried finding it on https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/)
I'm just really can't get over it.
Really appreciate any more clear answer on this!

Comment: I guess it would be a bit much to ask JB to keep and maintain a repository of all the loggers in all the popular libraries. Loggers are implementation specifics and not API and thus can change at any time. And there are LOTS of them.

Comment: Ahh yeah, this is excellent, why so skeptical-me LOL, Thank You!